# Randomly think about how the world will end because I have homework to do. Please help me think this through

Tags: gravity, sun, fusion

First off, I just want to say that i do not hold any degree of any kind, except a forklift certification but I do love space and I think about it to the point where I believe. As I am sitting in front of my computer screen, thinking/talking to myself- the craziest idea came to me and I need some smart people brainpower to evaluate this thought i have.
We know that in the center of the sun, atoms are fusing together to make helium which is heavier than hydrogen meaning it has more mass. The more mass an object in space has the stronger it gravitational pull on other objects. Which means that if the sun is gain mass in its core, as time progresses, the stronger its gravity gets effecting all the whole solar system. And since we are 2 cores in 1 and also contain a large amount of hydrogen our selves, the balance that keeps us anchored in space-time will be cut, our tilt is also worrisome because we are being pulled-by-the-head-effect(TM!). I also think the the color of light/ quality of light will be effected by the extra mass that is being produced by nuclear fusion. So either, we get pulled into the sun or the light changes speed/color/wavelength/ETA? burning our beautiful planet along with everything we know. But since mercury is closer to the sun and is a metal ball, its basically a bullet aimed directly at the sun core. I am starting to freak myself out. Instead of 4 billion years, we have like 4 million years and we're already 5 minutes away from doomsday!

So my question is, what is the probability of this happening? Of am I just creating the next blockbuster hit "Globally F'ed-Ubantu." Will Mercury get pulled closer and closer to the sun creating bigger sunspots = bigger solar flares that will light us up like a ball of nitrogen gas?? EEKK!!! seriously, I am wigging out. The future! NOOO!!! [randomlinkimadeupwiththeYearOfDeathcalledbcYnot](https://Lessthan4billionyears.com/*2488.16*)

Answer (score 1):

- The sun isn't gaining mass in its core - it's actually *losing* mass. If you take two protons and two neutrons and bind them together in a helium nucleus, the result is *less* massive than the sum of its constituent parts because the energy which binds them together makes a negative contribution to the mass.  Another way to look at this is that by the celebrated formula $E=mc^2$, all of the energy constantly pouring out of the sun is decreasing its mass. Beyond that, the outer layers of the sun are constantly being blown away (which we call the *solar wind*), so that leads to an extra contribution to the decreasing mass.  Of course, the rate at which the sun's mass decreases is incredibly small compared to its size - about 0.00000000001% per year - so the effect will not be noticeable for us.
- The light that is emitted by the sun is primarily determined by its temperature, so as its temperature changes the amount and wavelength distribution of the light will change along with it.
- Mercury is a planet made of rock, and is unrelated to the elemental metal Hg except for the fact that their names both trace back to the same mythological figure.

Besides that, I'm afraid your questions don't make much sense in the context of our present understanding physics. If you are interested in the fate of our sun (and by extension, the ultimate fate of the planet) you can find any number of documentaries or resources which discuss it, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJY3y5_k0do).